# Get dependencies of a given feature in the Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kbuild

I have been working on the Linux kernel these time: undertanding its build system and everything about kbuild.
My question is: is it possible to get, for a given feature of the kernel, all its dependency?

I know that there is a parser of `Kconfig` files of the kernel directory. Can we get something like an intermediate representation that could help us get the parents (or child) features of a selected features in a `.config`? Do we have functions that help us for getting parents or child of a given features?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What are the utilities/tools, specific functions that could help to do that? Or, what is the tool that does it as standalone?

Comment: Look into internals of http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/yocto-kernel-tools/tree/tools for the hints. As a rough approximation: http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/yocto-kernel-tools/tree/tools/symbol_why.py#n333